# how to realize animation of react-native art

Tags: animation, svg, react-native, path

In react-native art, it is easy to create a path and stroke or fill it. However, if I want to add a animation (e.g. appear or disappear) to a path, how to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library of mine based on another person's project in react-native, for now you can only animate Paths but more shapes and animations will be added in the future. Library and implementation can be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-animations